# What does the $c$ variable mean in this formula and how do I calculate it?: $Y'(t) = a + b X(t-1) + c Y(t-1)$?

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm writing code to calculate the following formula from http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411l696.htm

```
2. Use lagged versions of the variables in the regression model.

This allows varying amounts of recent history to be brought into the forecast
Lagging of independent variables is often necessary in order for the regression model to be able to predict the future--i.e., to predict what will happen in period t based on knowledge of what happened up to period t-1
Example: instead of regressing Y on X, regress Y on LAG(X,1) and LAG(Y,1)
The regression equation is now Ý(t) = a + bX(t-1) + cY(t-1)
```

I know that the a is the y intercept, the b is the coefficient for the independent variable but I'm not sure what the c is and how to calculate it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method to calculate $c$ (simulations with $a$ and $b$) is applying the ordinary least squares (OLS) algorithm. Practically, you need to create the a design matrix $\mathbf{X}$ of size $(n-1) \times 3$ and the response vector $\mathbf{y}$. The length of $\mathbf{y}$ will be $n-1$ as you start from $y_2$. The design matrix $\mathbf{X}$ contains three columns, the first one is all $1$s for the intercept, the second is the lagged $x$'s, and the third is the lagged $y$s. For example, the bottom row of $\mathbf{X}$ is $(1, x_{1}, y_{1})$, and the top row is $(1, x_{n-1}, y_{n-1})$.   To find the the OLS of $\mathbf{w} = (a, b,c)$ just compute 
$$
\hat{\mathbf{w}} = \mathbf{ (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This variable introduces the effect of the past output on the current output, hence, the ne lagged...
That is why you are sewing the i-1 part there

Comment: I know what the lag is doing but I'm only specifically asking about the c variable and what that is and how to calculate it. I know the lagged formula uses the past outputs

Comment: You will need to build the system matrix to get the equations:
{y(t)} = [{1} {x(t-1)} {y(t-1)}]{a;b;c}
y=Aa

Then solve for {a;b;c} = (Atranspose*A)^-1 * Atranspose y

The trick is creating the vectors y(t) and y(t-1) using the same data but with one time step time shift

Comment: The C variable represents the relation between the current time step and the previous one ... this is called an Auto-Regressive system

Comment: I already have the y values for the current and previous time steps but what is the formula then to calculate the c value?